# How do I find out if a Silverlight Control's property has a binding attached?

Tags: silverlight

I want to loop through the controls on a UserControl and set a property if the control isn't bound.

e.g, If I have these controls:

```
                <Button x:Name="uxButton" Content="Foo"/>
                <Button x:Name="uxButton2" Content="{Binding Foo}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="uxText" Text="Blah"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock x:Name="uxText2" Text="{Binding Blah}"></TextBlock>
```

I would want to set the Content property on uxButton but not on uxButton2.
I would want to set the Text property on uxText but not on uxText2

I'm using Silverlight 2.0 (but if this were easier in 3.0 I'd like to hear).

How do I know that uxButton2 and uxText2 are bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer seems to be no. :(

In WPF there is a GetBindingExpression method.  No such feature in Silverlight: http://silverlight.net/forums/t/47216.aspx

Although this IS present in Silverlight 3 : [GetBindingExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.getbindingexpression%28vs%2E96%29.aspx)